# How to add items into specific Id using the react array map method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Here is my sample array which contains the id and item and item notes description.

```
let sampleArr = [
   {
     id:1,
     item:"item",
     notes:["one"]
   },
   {
     id:2,
     item:"item2",
     notes:["one","two"]
   },
   {
     id:3,
     item:"item3",
     notes:["one","two"]
   }
]
```

Here I want to add the notes into id:3 with the notes:"three" so I am expecting my final output should be like into the sample array.

```
{    
    id:3,
    item:"item3",
    notes:["one","two","three"]
 }
```

Comment: Yes you are right, deleted my comment. Never mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gist here is to only `concat` the new `note` when `item.id === id` otherwise just return the old item

```
const addNoteById = (note, id) =>{
    return sampleArr.map(item =>({
        ...item,
        notes : item.id === id ? item.notes.concat(note) : item.notes
    }))
}
```

```js
const sampleArr = [{id:1,item:"item", notes:["one"]},{id:2,item:"item2",notes:["one","two"]},{id:3,item:"item3",notes:["one","two"]}]

const addNoteById = (note, id) =>{
    return sampleArr.map(item =>({
        ...item,
        notes : item.id === id ? item.notes.concat(note) : item.notes
    }))
}

const result = addNoteById('foo', 3)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I can not write this  way like  
let returnData;
returnData = sampleArr.map(item =>{
        ...item,
        notes : item.id === id ? item.notes.concat(note) : item.notes
    })

Comment: @Pintu you need to wrap return value by `()`, i.e `sampleArr.map(item => ({...`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function which search element based on id and update value

```js
let sampleArr = [{id: 1,item: "item",notes: ["one"]},{id: 2,item: "item2",notes: ["one", "two"]},{id: 3,item: "item3",notes: ["one", "two"]}]

const updateNotes = (id,value) =>{
  return sampleArr.map(v=> {
    return v.id == id ? {...v, notes: [...v.notes, value]} : v
  })
}

console.log(updateNotes(3,'three'))
```